# Segmenting brain images (Dicom format) using region-growing algorithm

Tags: performance, algorithm, image, matlab

I have a list of images in a folder where `num` denotes the index of image and I used `num` to run the iterations in a "for loop". The code is supposed to segment brain part from the brain CT images. Here is the link for [region growing algorithm](http://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19084-region-growing).

How do I increase the performance of my region-growing algorithm?

```
% CORD_XY(1),CORD_XY(2) is the seed point
% LEN Denotes the number of images in a folder    
% num is used to iterate in "for loop"
% "img" here is single image from the folder in DICOM format

for num= 1:LEN 
    img = dicomread(files(num,1).name);
    [row, col] = size(img);
    th = 20;
    diff = 10;

    J = regiongrowing(img, CORD_XY(1), CORD_XY(2), th);
    value1 = sum(sum(J > 0));

    if num > 10)
        th = 55;
    elseif num <= 10
        while diff < 0.2 * value1 && diff ~= 0 && th < 60
            value1 = sum(sum(J > 0));
            th = th + 10;
            J = regiongrowing(double(img), CORD_XY(1), CORD_XY(2), th);
            value2 = sum(sum(J > 0));
            diff = value2 - value1; 
        end
    end
end  

J = regiongrowing(img, CORD_XY(1), CORD_XY(2), th-10);
```

Comment: @Santosh how many iterations does this typically take until your convergence criteria are met?

Comment: It takes 4 to 5 iterations which i feel is very less. I am not using the above technique anymore and looking for alternatives. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the Image Processing Toolbox, so I can't test your code, but I'll go through what I can.

**Never do `diff = 10;`** `diff` is a useful builtin function in Matlab, so using it as a variable name will cause the function to be useless. The same goes with `max`, `sum`, `size` and so on.

`value1 = sum(sum(J > 0));` is a bit faster than `value1 = sum(J(:)>0);`, so with regards to performance you did the right thing. In my opinion however, `sum(J(:)>0)` is a bit cleaner, and it can also be scaled to more dimensions.

Instead of `elseif N <= 10` you can simply do `else`, as they mean the same thing in this context.

If it takes 4-5 iterations pretty consistently, then maybe you can increase the initial value of `th` to e.g. `th = 40`. It will result in fewer iterations for most images, so a faster algorithm. You might benefit from guessing a good value, run the algorithm, if you don't hit convergence, jump to a lower value. This will perform better for most of the images, but will be slower for some. In total, it's likely faster.